# How to increase the distance between nodes and node orientation with TikZ graph drawing library

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am creating a graph using TikZ (it is in ConTeXt, but the idea should be the same in LaTeX):

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[graphs, graphdrawing]
\usegdlibrary[layered]

\defineframed[fixed][width=5mm,height=5mm, frame=off]


\starttext
\tikz \graph [layered layout, nodes={draw, circle}]
{
start__\fixed{$x_0$},
x1U__\fixed{$x_{1U}$},
x1M__\fixed{$x_{1M}$},
x1L__\fixed{$x_{1L}$},
x2U__\fixed{$x_{2U}$},
x2M__\fixed{$x_{2M}$},
x2L__\fixed{$x_{2L}$},
x3U__\fixed{$x_{3U}$},
x3M__\fixed{$x_{3M}$},
x3L__\fixed{$x_{3L}$},
start -> { x1U, x1M, x1L},
x1U ->   { x2U, x2M, x2L},
x1M ->   { x2U, x2M, x2L},
x1L ->   { x2U, x2M, x2L},
x2U ->   { x3U, x3M, x3L},
x2M ->   { x3U, x3M, x3L},
x2L ->   { x3U, x3M, x3L}
};


\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

1. How do I increase the distance between nodes?
2. How do I make the graph grow from left to right rather than top to bottom?

I am afraid that I am lost in the TikZ documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several keys allowing you to control the distance between nodes; in the code below I used `sibling distance` and `level sep` (there's also `node distance`); they are described in Section **27.3 Padding and Node Distances** (of the manual for the CVS version).

To specify in which direction the neighbours of a node should grow, you can use the `grow` key (There are several other possibilities using some other keys described in Section **27.5 Orienting a Graph**).

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[graphs, graphdrawing]
\usegdlibrary[layered]

\defineframed[fixed][width=5mm,height=5mm, frame=off]


\starttext
\tikz \graph [layered layout, grow=right,sibling distance=3cm,level sep=2cm,nodes={draw, circle}]
{
start__\fixed{$x_0$},
x1U__\fixed{$x_{1U}$},
x1M__\fixed{$x_{1M}$},
x1L__\fixed{$x_{1L}$},
x2U__\fixed{$x_{2U}$},
x2M__\fixed{$x_{2M}$},
x2L__\fixed{$x_{2L}$},
x3U__\fixed{$x_{3U}$},
x3M__\fixed{$x_{3M}$},
x3L__\fixed{$x_{3L}$},
start -> { x1U, x1M, x1L},
x1U ->   { x2U, x2M, x2L},
x1M ->   { x2U, x2M, x2L},
x1L ->   { x2U, x2M, x2L},
x2U ->   { x3U, x3M, x3L},
x2M ->   { x3U, x3M, x3L},
x2L ->   { x3U, x3M, x3L}
};


\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the tikz manual or the graphs library manual?